# Como evitar cargar los datos del usuario logueado en la pagina user.php?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo dos páginas, `perfil.php` y `user.php`, perfil.php abre cuando me logueo con mi usuario y entro a mi perfil y user.php es cuando busco por nombre de usuario y me lleva al perfil del usuario buscado.

¿Cómo hago para evitar que al realizar la búsqueda del mismo usuario logueado esto me lleve a la `user.php`,en vez de ir a `perfil.php`

La búsqueda la hago mediante un auto-complete que me muestra los usuarios según lo que escribo.

**PHP**

```
 <?php

include("conexion.php");

if(isset($_POST['query']))
{

 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE nombre LIKE '%". 
 $_POST['query']."%'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 $output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';

 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 )
 {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

          $output .= '<li><img style="border-radius:50%;" id="pic-search"
         src="'.$row['Fotos'].'" width ="100px" height="100px"></img><a 
         href="user.php?Id='.$row['Id'].'">'.$row['nombre'].' 
       '.$row['apellido'].'</a></li>';
    }
  }
 else
  {
     $output .= '<li>Not found</li>';
  }

 $output .= '</ul>';
 echo $output;
  }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Supongo que guardas el usuario logueado un una `$_SESSION['id_usario']`.</strike>

Según comentario del OP tiene el id del usuario en la variable `$my_id` guardado.

Entonces buscas en tu consulta todos menos el usario logueado...

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM personas 
          WHERE nombre LIKE '%". $_POST['query']."%' 
          AND id != '". $my_id."'";
```

**Nota aparte**:

Usa por favor sentencias preparadas para evitar [Inyecciones SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Comment: +1 por las inyecciones... tema serio

Comment: @aldanux el usuario logueado lo tengo en un archivo aparte,el cual incluyo mediante "include()",y el id del usuario logueado esta guardado en una variable llamada "$my_id"

Comment: @luis - Ok... era solo un ejemplo ya que no sabia en que variable estaba guardado... pero la consulta queda igual solo cambiando la variable... respuesta actualizada

Comment: Gracias.Lo puse de esta forma:                                                                    -$query = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE Id !='$my_id' AND nombre LIKE '%". $_POST['query']."%'";                                                                          -                                                                                                                    - Pero tuve que batallar mucho ya que ponia session_start().en ambos archivos y me causaban interferencia,ademas de que no encontraba la forma de llamar la variable $my_id.Thanks.!! Aprendiendo!!!

Comment: Me alegro @luis... sigue así! Saludos